# restore wordpress deleted menus

Tags: wordpress, menu, header

I am new in wordpress
I have database backup of my wordpress site
and by-mistake I have deleted all top menus
can I restore from database backup, or it is being stored in some files
which tables I need to restore
please help!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately its not possible to restore deleted menus in WordPress using WP systems.

you can only restore if you have a recent database backup.

Comment: I have backup but it has thousands of posts and i am having trouble to restore large backup.sql file, I want to restore specific tables or records

Comment: why you do not restore the entire database? .. if you have new posts or pages export them using `Tools > Export` then restore all tables . and then the exported posts and pages .

Answer (score 2):

If you did it through the WP backend, you need to restore the entries from wp_posts and wp_postmeta.  Look for the nav_menu_item post type, grab any row that uses that.  Then note the associated IDs and grab the rows from wp_postmeta that use those IDs as Post ID.  That should restore your menu.

Comment: will it be ok to restore wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables only?

Comment: Obviously you should back this up before you restore records and you should do this locally first to confirm.  I believe all records pertaining to menus are kept in those two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with wpml installed, turns out I had to restore the: wp_term_relationships table where the term_taxonomy_id matched the id of the menu (careful menu id is not the same as post id)